# Update Graph (chart control) on another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, graph, charts

I have a **C# Windows Form application** which contains a **MainForm** and a **GraphView form**. Main form **continuously receive** **Current and Temperature values from USB port** and stored in a **Structure array List<>**. During these process when we click a button in main form, another form (GraphView) form with a **chart control** will open and plot the graph with ,

**X-Axis : Time in minute,
Y-Axis : Current in mA,
Y2-axis : Temperature in °C,**

What can I do?

In my **MainForm**

```
    public struct Record
    {
        public byte ChanelNumber;
        public UInt16 SerialNumber;
        public byte SampleNumber;
        public string ChanelVoltage;
        public string ChanelCurrent;
        public string ChannelTemparature;
    }

List<Record>[] ChannelRecords = new List<Record>[12];
```

**ChannelRecords** will store received data from **USB port**.

```
    private void btnGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = new GraphView();
        g.Show();
        Task task = new Task(SendToGraph);
        task.Start();
    }

    private void SendToGraph()
    {
        while (true)
        {
               g.UpdateGraph(ChannelRecords[0]);
        }

    }
```

And in **GraphView form**

```
    public void UpdateGraph(List<MainForm.Record> Records)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (Records != null)
                for (int j = 0; j < Records.Count; j++)
                {
                    if ((j % 5) != 0) continue;
                    var CurVal = float.Parse(Records[j].ChanelCurrent);
                    var TempVal = float.Parse(Records[j].ChanelCurrent);
                    chart.Series[0].Points.AddY(CurVal);
                    chart.Series[1].Points.AddY(TempVal);

                }
        });
    }
```

This is the way I tried. But the graph cannot update. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use user control for graph, it will be easy as well as systematic

Comment: you can also do it by constructor over loading of graph form, when needed close the form,pass array in constructor by new keyword and reopen it

Comment: other method is globally declaring second form in c# first form, and creating a public method in second form to update graph and calling it from first form